# How to convert vcard to text?

Tags: android, share, contacts, vcf-vcard

I want to share contact to my application  from phonebook to vcard format. How to take shared-vcard formatted contact information?

```
Uri streamExtra = sharedIntent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);

**Result:** content://com.android.contacts/contacts/as_vcard/profile
```

Comment: have look this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12659323/android-get-vcard-data-from-intent

Comment: Thank you. Your link provide that reading uri.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [this library](https://github.com/mangstadt/ez-vcard) to parse a VCard and extract the info.

An example of how to do this:

```
VCard vcard = Ezvcard.parse(str).first();
String fullName = vcard.getFormattedName().getValue();
String lastName = vcard.getStructuredName().getFamily();
```

If you need to share the contact info with another app, you can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28545346/saving-vcard-contact-via-intent)

Comment: thanxx i used this library and run it.